# Blacklist CLI commands on a Nexus

Tags: switching, cli, cisco-nexus-7k, nx-os, cisco-eem

Is there a way to make a Cisco Nexus 7k to reject a CLI command?

Everyone knows about the impact, when you want to add a VLAN to a trunk, and if you forget the keyword a`add`.

If you do this with a VPC N7k pair on a VPC port-channel dot1q trunk, the VLANs will go to suspended as long as they're not allowed on both VPC trunks.

Is there a way to make the cli reject the command if you forget the `add` in:

```
int po[X]

switchport trunk allowed vlan add [Y]
```

EDIT:
In ios this could be achieved with something like

event cli pattern [regex] skip yes

Comment: In our environment, we use Cisco ISE as TACACS, you can specifically specify each command allowed for each user or user group. I just checked and it is possible to reject the command `switchport trunk allowed vlan`. Here you can also allow the command if it has the `add` after. But i guess you are thinking about a way to block it directly via CLI?

Comment: In a larger sense, it's not possible to idiot proof systems like data center switches. A better approach is to use change management and test environments and maintenance windows to mitigate the likelihood and impact of configuration errors.

Comment: @Cown thats interesting, probably we'd need to change many things as you probably can't just replace your tacacs server with an ISE. I was looking for a way to block it directly via cli, without having to implement additional services.

Comment: @Todd Wilcox It could be quite expensive to roll those configurations out via change management. A task which could be done in minutes by one person can turn to one which lasts hours or days with many people involved. If that mistake happens 0.01 times during those configurations, it is questionable if there is a benefit.

Comment: In the cisco catalyst series (6000') you had the event manager, and shell scripting in ios. So you were able to create my asked behavior via script.

Comment: @Rene By that logic it doesn't seem worth the effort and risk to blacklist commands if the odds of a misconfiguration are so small. And change management, unlike arbitrary command restrictions, has many other benefits.

Comment: @Rene, change management, reviews and approvals, etc. are now mandatory parts of network engineering.

Comment: You can have change management involved for every tiny modification with enough staff. And you are totally right, that change management is mandatory in network engineering. Nevertheless you can overdo it, in my opinion. I'd like to turn back to topic, it was not my intention to start a principled discussion :) Maybe someone has an idea - With cisco ios you could do smth like: event cli pattern "switchport trunk allowed vlan [0-9]+$" skip yes                Unfortunately the "event cli" doesn't exist any more in nx-os

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, it can be done by this:

```
config t
event manager applet protectmefromdoingstupid
description "goes here"
event cli match "switchport trunk allowed vlan [0-9]+.*"
action 1.0 put "There was no 'add' in that statement! If you know what you are doing, run 'terminal event-manager bypass' and 'no terminal event-manager bypass', when you are done."
```

from:
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus7000/sw/system-management/guide/b_Cisco_Nexus_7000_Series_NX-OS_System_Management_Configuration_Guide/b_Cisco_Nexus_7000_Series_NX-OS_System_Management_Configuration_Guide_chapter_010010.html

Following note from cisco is critical here :)

> If you want to allow the triggered event to process any default actions, you must configure the EEM policy to allow the default action. For example, if you match a CLI command in a match statement, you must add the event-default action statement to the EEM policy or EEM will not allow the CLI command to execute. You can use the terminal event-manager bypass command to allow all EEM policies with CLI matches to execute the CLI command.

I'll test this and report back.

EDIT:
Improved the regex (.* instead $), thanks to @Ron Maupin for the hint.

Something about regex interpretation on a nx7k can be found here:

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/sw/4_0/nx-os/fundamentals/configuration/guide2/fun_nx-os_book/fun_3about_cli.html#wp1237003

EDIT AFTER TESTING:

it doesn't work like I suggested, there are some weird behaviors and it seems many commands in the cisco documentation doesn't exist (neither on a N7K with nxos 6*(<- I know its old) nor on a n9k with nxos 7*)

I tested a workaround and it works like I wanted to:

```
conf t
event manager applet protect1
event cli match "conf t ; int * ; switchport trunk allowed vlan 1*"
event manager applet protect2
event cli match "conf t ; int * ; switchport trunk allowed vlan 2*"
event manager applet protect3
event cli match "conf t ; int * ; switchport trunk allowed vlan 3*"
event manager applet protect4
event cli match "conf t ; int * ; switchport trunk allowed vlan 4*"
event manager applet protect5
event cli match "conf t ; int * ; switchport trunk allowed vlan 5*"
event manager applet protect6
event cli match "conf t ; int * ; switchport trunk allowed vlan 6*"
event manager applet protect7
event cli match "conf t ; int * ; switchport trunk allowed vlan 7*"
event manager applet protect8
event cli match "conf t ; int * ; switchport trunk allowed vlan 8*"
event manager applet protect9
event cli match "conf t ; int * ; switchport trunk allowed vlan 9*"
end
terminal no event manager bypass
```

Some explanation:

According to the documentation, it should interpret this as cli regex. But it don't. Maybe it is because you need to give the absolut path in the event definition.
Mandatory are as well the spaces around the semicolons.

I am not very happy with this (happy that it works but its somehow ugly) - tested improvements are very appreciated!

Comment: What happens in the case of a list of VLANs? `switchport trunk allowed vlan 5,7,9-11` That would still replace the current allowed VLANs instead of adding to them.

Comment: That '$' should match anything else after.

Comment: No, the `$` matches the end of the string. You are only matching numbers on the command.

Comment: Oh, it was intended to do this. I wanted to have something like .* instead of the $ .

Comment: @RonMaupin , just realized that I probably don't need anything else after the [0-9]+  . If I'd want to have a whole line match I'd need to put   ^   at the beginning and    $    to the end, right?

Comment: Correct, but my caution is that your regex only works for a single VLAN. Trying to add multiple VLANs will still mess you up without an `add` because your regex without the `.*` doesn't catch that.

Comment: @Rene After you tested with your workaround, what would you like to achieve?

Comment: @HungTran I'd like to have that in one policy instead of nine. And I would like to print some text to the cli. The action statement 'put' doesn't seem to exist. Another approach would be a script, which implements some dialog like: Are you sure you want to REPLACE the vlan pattern? [y/n] n.

Comment: @Rene Unfortunately, with EEM on Nexus, in regular command expressions, only the asterisk (*) symbol can be used for replace the arguments [Cisco document here](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus5600/sw/system_management/7x/b_5600_System_Mgmt_Config_7x/b_6k_System_Mgmt_Config_7x_chapter_010001.html). We cannot use other characters as we normally use for regular expressions. I have added my answer below.

Comment: @Rene Please let me know whether you checked and tested my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using EEM on Nexus, you can try with the following two applets. I have tested them out and they work as expected.

```
event manager applet TrunkAdd
  event cli match "conf t ; int * ; switchport trunk allowed vlan add *"
  action 1.0 event-default

event manager applet TrunkBlock
  event cli match "conf t ; int * ; switchport trunk allowed vlan *"
```

- 1st applet is to allow the command `switchport trunk
  allowed vlan add ...` as we have `event-default`action.
- 2nd applet is to deny the command `switchport trunk allowed vlan` without `add`

**Test results:**

```
#show run int Ethernet4/1    

interface Ethernet4/1
  switchport
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,30,40,60
  no shutdown

#conf t
(config)# interface Ethernet4/1
(config-if)#switchport trunk allowed vlan 20
% Command blocked by event manager policy
(config-if)#switchport trunk allowed vlan add 20
(config-if)#end

#show run int Ethernet4/1

interface Ethernet4/1
  switchport
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,30,40,60
  no shutdown
```

Be aware that, with EEM on Nexus, in regular command expressions, only the asterisk (*) symbol can be used for replace the arguments ([Cisco doc here](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus5600/sw/system_management/7x/b_5600_System_Mgmt_Config_7x/b_6k_System_Mgmt_Config_7x_chapter_010001.html)). We cannot use other characters (such as ^, $, ., [ ], *, ... ) as we normally use for regular expressions. That is why I think we cannot use one applet in this case.

I hope it is helpful.

Comment: I still have a hard time wrapping my head around allowing people in a data center to make changes without a proper review and approval of the proposed changes.

Comment: @RonMaupin I totally agree that we should have a CRB (Change Review Board) within Network and IT teams to review and approve all changes (with all steps and commands clearly documented). And change owner should follow exactly what are written and approved.

Comment: I liked my solution more because it will allow commands like "switchport trunk allowed vlan none" or "switchport trunk allowed vlan remove" and only denies what I wanted to. Both provided answers here are of course similar and both are functional.

Comment: @Rene That is okay :) And bear in mind that, the solution here was based on your problem description, as there were no things like  "...vlan none" and "....vlan remove" in our question :). If you need those commands, just follow my example to create "TrunkRemove" and "TrunkNone" applet scripts (like "TrunkAdd") before "TrunkBlock".

Answer (score 1):

I did the same think using RBAC locally on our Nexus 7010:

```
role name Soporte-2
  rule 55 permit command configure terminal ; interface * ; switchport trunk allowed vlan add *
  rule 50 deny command configure terminal ; interface * ; switchport trunk allowed vlan *
  rule 5 permit read-write
```

Hope this help.